# Are Items safe lying around my house?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm a bit of an untidy thief and often end up with a few things lying around the house. I've also left open a book next to my Alchemy lab in Whiterun for cosmetic and reference purposes. Obviously the proper way to keep all this stuff safe is to put it away in my chests etc which are safe containers.

My question is; is this stuff safe in my house *without* being stored in a container?

It so far for me seems to be so since a lot of random replaceable stuff hasn't disappeared however I have a few books that I'm pretty sure I can't replace (PS3 so no console :( ) and don't want to take the chance.

Comment: Well i'll bet they'd be a hell of a lot safer than my stuff was!I don't know about other people but I no longer use containers!!! I've just returned to whiterun from riften after deciding to finally do the thieves guild at level 30, only to find 2 out if the 3 containers I'd been using at warmaidens since level 3 no longer possed all my orc armour set or ebony armour set, neither the multitude of weapons I'd enchanted and trinkets ready to be sold on a rainy day. Not to mention all my mining supplies including 30+ dragon bones and scales for when I reached 100 smithing...

Comment: I heard on the wiki that in your house, even if the item is safe, they could be stolen because of the fact that no one is in the house. Have your housecarl, a spouse, or anyone else in the house to keep it safe.

Comment: @galacticninja, what makes you think this is the dupe? It is older, has an answer, and appears more popular.

Comment: @Timelord64 This question is a dupe because it is asking the exact same thing as the *older* question. What made you say that this question's older? Look again. The original, *older* question already had an upvoted answer before this question was even posted.

Comment: @galacticninja, my bad. It's off by a out a month. That said, I would support the other being the dupe, only on the basis that this question has a couple more votes, and higher voted main answers. The other question has more answers, but they are not of as high quality. This question has also been viewed twice as much (not that that is a good metric). If this was caught at the start, it would be an easy dupe. But it's been up for four years, so I'm in favour of looking at quality, instead.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes but with a few FYI's and 1 exception.

Items are safe for the most part but can and do tend to get kicked around either by you or house guests. Items when first dropped in your house create a "spawn trigger point" this meaning

Say I drop a nice helmet to display on some shelf, so I drop it on the floor then
Drag and drop it onto the shelf,then exit the house and come back later.

You will now find the helmet *not* on the shelf where you moved it but in the place it first was dropped. Now if you drag and drop from this point it should stay on the shelf or whereever you decide to place it, rule being redecorate with the item *after* you have initially dropped it,exited and returned. FYI on rare occasions even this rule breaks and the first drop and drag holds ,so go figure :)

Exceptions to both the safe and placement rules.

When you own more than 1 house and you have say already redecorated using the rules above
And then bought another house and did the same,THEN decide to go visit your first house you *may* find things or items out of place - even sometimes finding the whole house *exploded*. Most items regardless of whether you ever touched them or not get thrown everywhere.

This is because of a "Spacial Placement BUG" which sometimes links owned property.

The last is the safe exception.

There are times and I have personally had this happen where you drop an item even a
unique and irreplaceable item down in your house and it will either go *poof* then and 
There or right after you exit and re-enter said house. This has happened when only one house is owned as well as when multiple houses are owned.

It tends to happen with smaller items but some large items i.e. swords or shields or staff.

This seems to be a rare event but like I said it happened to me so to define rare,
I've played over 500hrs real time and have so much stuff whose to say, I only noticed
because it was a rare book and I was placing it for display on a coffee table in Whiterun and when I reentered it was gone,this being after I dropped it,then exited reentered and placed it. This is the only item I know I have had go poof.

I hope this helped

Answer (score 11):

Yes they are absolutely safe, but with 1 caveat.  Things tend to get redistributed when its inside your house.  For instance, I had all the claws I've collected from random dungeons organized on a big table all facing down.  But every once in a while I might find them all scattered or on the floor.

So you do risk a chance that an item might end up clipping under the floor so you can't find it anymore.

Also, the risk is higher for losing small things like gems and rings.

To be safe (and make things easier to locate), I would put the books onto a book shelf and try to sort the rest of your stuff into various containers.

Comment: I never bothered to confirm this, but I did at one point get the impression that buying furniture deleted the items I had previously stored in the standard container in my house in Whiterun.

Comment: @bkzland - This did not occur for me, I stored a few items in the standard container before buying any furniture, and all the items were still present after buying all the furniture sets.

Comment: I've also used the first container i Whiterun and upgraded later on without any problems.